# Delegating Authentication to Oauth Server - Principal null

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, cas, jasig

I'm using 5.3 version and I've configured CAS for delegating authentication to an external Oauth server. My cas.properties looks like:

```
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].clientName=oauth1
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].id=
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].secret=
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].authUrl=https://xxxxxxxxxxx/sso/oauth/controller/Server/action/authorize/
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].tokenUrl=https://xxxxxxxx/sso/oauth/controller/Server/action/token/
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].profileUrl=https://xxxxxxxx/sso/oauth/controller/Server/action/profile/?fields=username
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].principalAttributeId=username
```

In terms of service (JSON) this is the configuration:

```
{
  @class: org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService
  serviceId: ID
  name: name
  theme: default
  id: 1
  description: name
  logoutType: FRONT_CHANNEL
  attributeReleasePolicy:
  {
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.ReturnAllAttributeReleasePolicy"
  }
  logoutUrl: https://yyyyyy/logout
  accessStrategy:
  {
    @class: org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceAccessStrategy
    order: 0
    enabled: true
    ssoEnabled: true
    delegatedAuthenticationPolicy:
    {
      "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceDelegatedAuthenticationPolicy"
      "allowedProviders" : [ "java.util.ArrayList", [ "oauth1" ] ]
    }
    requireAllAttributes: false
    caseInsensitive: false
  }
}
```

CAS is able to get properly the information from Oauth protocol but when it tries to get the Principal, the answer is always:`

```
2019-10-31 14:37:41,070 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationBuilder] - <Recording authentication handler result success under key [ClientAuthenticationHandler]>
2019-10-31 14:37:41,070 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <Authentication handler [ClientAuthenticationHandler] successfully authenticated [ClientCredential(typedIdUsed=false, userProfile=#OAuth20Profile# | id: null | attributes: {access_token=8b2eaaa3c8d3d51233df5da4047889c8530a7df4, username=apotheke_alphega} | roles: [] | permissions: [] | isRemembered: false | clientName: oauth1 | linkedId: null |, credentials=#OAuth20Credentials# | code: 5f0d498cfc347b66de544d98ce309d5f1f200716 | accessToken: com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuth2AccessToken@3b3a98c |, clientName=oauth1)]>
2019-10-31 14:37:41,074 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.config.CasPersonDirectoryConfiguration] - <Configured single-row JDBC attribute repository for [jdbc:mysql://b2bde-uat-db02.mysql.database.azure.com/lr_b2b_core?useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=true]>
2019-10-31 14:37:41,086 WARN [org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <[ClientAuthenticationHandler] is configured to use [ChainingPrincipalResolver(principalFactory=org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.DefaultPrincipalFactory@1, chain=[EchoingPrincipalResolver(), PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver(attributeRepository=org.apereo.services.persondir.support.CachingPersonAttributeDaoImpl@63f2c17b, principalFactory=org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.DefaultPrincipalFactory@1, returnNullIfNoAttributes=true, principalNameTransformer=org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.resolvers.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver$$Lambda$130/1783977388@2488625b, principalAttributeNames=username, useCurrentPrincipalId=true)])] but it does not support [ClientCredential(typedIdUsed=false, userProfile=#OAuth20Profile# | id: null | attributes: {access_token=8b2eaaa3c8d3d51233df5da40478df4, username=user} | roles: [] | permissions: [] | isRemembered: false | clientName: oauth1 | linkedId: null |, credentials=#OAuth20Credentials# | code: 5f0d498cfc347b66de544d98ce30916 | accessToken: com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuth2AccessToken@3b3a98c |, clientName=oauth1)], which suggests a configuration problem.>
2019-10-31 14:37:41,087 WARN [org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <Principal resolution handled by [$Proxy401] produced a null principal. This is likely due to misconfiguration or missing attributes; CAS will attempt to use the principal produced by the authentication handler, if any.>
2019-10-31 14:37:41,087 WARN [org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <Principal resolution for authentication by [ClientAuthenticationHandler] produced a null principal.>
2019-10-31 14:37:41,087 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <Final principal resolved for this authentication event is [null]>
```

Could you help me? I'm very block and I can't find any real example

Kind Regards

Comment: I would recommend to use debugger and put breakpoints in lines where the warnings are logged. At least, you will understand what is missing from the configuration.

Comment: Thanks @leopal , I'm not compiling CAS else using the overlay solution (direct binary). Debug trace is enabled but I'm not found any information

Comment: You don't have to compile CAS itself. For example search for `PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager` on your IDE, download sources/javadoc jar and put breakpoints on its source code. I am able to do what I 've described also by using overlay.

Comment: Thanks @leopal, but my challenge is that the Oauth2 Server that I'm using is out of my network and I can't connect it with my local environment only from the environment that I'm getting the issue. With Google is working ok

Comment: Post the full logs. Always.